# Sass parent select (&) after element tag name?

Tags: html, css, sass

When using SASS (SCSS syntax specifically), is it possible to use the parent selector (ampersand, `&`), right after an element name in a nested group of rules like this? I'm using some BEM naming conventions:

```
.container {

  &__element {  // <-- This works fine

  }

  div&__element {  // <-- This does NOT work

  }
}
```

Trying to compile out to this:

```
.container {
}
.container__element {
}
div.container__element {
}
```

But instead I get an error:

```
Invalid CSS after "div": expected "{", was "&__checkbox"

"&__checkbox" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.
```

Am I missing something about the syntax here? Is it just not possible to do this?

Comment: You also have a typo (hint: if Sass were to compile it, you'd have a selector that looks like `.div..container__element`, which is invalid).

Comment: Thanks fixed the typo. Similar error.

Comment: Which the question I marked this as a duplicate of addresses...